# execute the master playbook using python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible

how can i execute a ansible playbook using python script? i need to invoke the master playbook using python. The master playbook is encrypted using ansible vault. The password can be passed in python script. How do i write it

Comment: How can i write an ansible task to check whether the task is encrypted or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Subprocess module allows you to run whatever you'd like

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run([
    'ansible-playbook',
    '-i', 'inventory.yaml',
    '-e', 'secret@passfile',
    'master.yaml']
)
```

Comment: is there a way to check the file eg .yml is encrypted or not in a when condition in ansible? What is the parameter i need to pass?

Comment: How can I right the same in ansible is there any parameter

Comment: I have few roles I do not want other users to see this code so I will be encrypting each file using ansible vault. Eg I have two role encrypted individually through ansible vault and the vault key is passed using python script only. I do not want to store the vault key in text anywhere in my folder except the python script. While running the play books I have written task for encryption and decryption. But if intruppted in between then it through error so I need to add condition to check the file is encrypted or not

Comment: Which one would you suggest to lock the playbooks using a single python script or as above. Sorry not good at python. Ansible can’t find the parameters to pass in when condition

Comment: If user interrupts the playbook during decryption he can get the code is there a way to avoid this? Either he should to terminate the execution or before termination it should call an ansible taks to encrypt and only then terminate

Comment: Use `try/except`.